# how can i parse json object using javascript..?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var Response = $.parseJSON(data.d);
```

this code is not working..
my json object is

```
[{"ItemId":1,"ItemName":"Sizzler"},{"ItemId":2,"ItemName":"Starter"},{"ItemId":3,"ItemName":"Salad"}]
```

How can i parse this?

Comment: I would guess that, as you're using `data.d`, the JSON is already parsed. jQuery *will*, in most scenarios, detect JSON and parse it for you. I'd see if `typeof data === "object"`, and if it is, you should be able to iterate over `data` (as an array).

Comment: ITs not a JSON, here JSON is inside an array.

Comment: okies then how to parse this..
will you please explain me.

Comment: @kiranvj that is still valid JSON.

Comment: For reference, there is no such thing as a "JSON object" (with the arguable exception of the actual `JSON` module, but that's nitpicking).  JSON is a format for *strings that represent* objects.  If you have an object that's not a string, it's by definition not JSON; it's just an *object*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the solution. I have included 2 jquery and because of their clash my code was not working..
my working code is :
    var jsonp = data.d;

```
var lang = '';

var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);

$.each(obj, function() {

    lang += this['ItemId'] + " ";

});
alert(lang);
```